# Code optimizer extension for Dreamweaver?

Tags: dreamweaver

Due to my neat coding style, my pages take up like 30% more space on both my server and the output HTML.
Is there any free extension for Dreamweaver to automatically optimize my pages when uploading them? I mean not only HTML, but also PHP, CSS and JS...
Actually, removing unnecessary tabs, spaces and new lines will just do the trick.

After removing the unnecessary spaces, tabs and new lines from my PHP code, the page loaded three times faster so this is important...

Comment: .... Bro. That's a whole lot of tabs and spaces. A 30% increase? Wow.

Comment: @Griffin I've had plenty of time to work on my coding style since I asked this question. It used to be a true horror. :/

Comment: Wow this was asked 4 years ago. It came up in the active yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it up to remove trailing spaces and tabs on saves (I think that's set by default)

But honestly, you might want to check your server settings or performance...

I have never noticed any change in loading time when I started making better organized code.

And if it would effect loading times that much, then I think that most programmers would also prefer to remove all 'styling' but as a matter of fact, even the best programmers keep the 'styling' so they and others can edit it easily

When you say 30% change in file size do you mean from 10kb to 12kb? because that just doesn't matter

Comment: I've had a 6,5 KB file and it turned 5 KB after optimizing the PHP only. It loaded 3 times faster, just like I said. But I'll look closer at the settings...

Comment: I'm affraid you either have an incredibly slow connection to your server or the server itself is overloaded? 6,5kb to 5kb should hardly make any noticable difference

Comment: First of all, I care about bandwidth a lot. Secondly... It still makes a difference. My pages are HUGE.

Comment: @Vercas - See here for some info on PHP whitespace and what you do and don't have to worry about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1747373/php-source-code-whitespace

Comment: There are hundreds of websites on the same server and it's busy most of the times...

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver has it's own tidy tool that works well if you select the "format sounce code" icon which is a paint bucket and click "apply source formatting" this will remove spaces etc and generally tidy the code up.

Comment: I do not intent do format my code. I want to be able to maintain it. I would like to have my code uploaded formatted.